# What kind of pump works for hard to reach kids valves?

Tags: children

Could you recommend a pump that can inflate this?  I want to jump off a bridge right now :/

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like you need to push the valve in from the back (i.e. put your thumb on the tire side and push towards the rim so that the valve portrudes more out) because the tire pressure is low. Then, hook on the pump and start pumping.

Otherwise, you can start with whatever pump you have and buy an extension hose or valve extender. The type of valve on there is a Schrader valve.

Comment: And, while the asker is at it, he should adjust the tube and tyre so the valve is perpendicular to the rim. That'll give more room to work with, as well as subjecting it to less stress when the bike's being ridden.

Comment: The inner tube isn't correctly seated. The valve should point straight towards the axle of the wheel. There's a serious danger that it will be sheared off resulting in a sudden blowout. Maybe less so on a child's bike but still.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I am not very handy and assumed the bike was poorly made.  I had tried pushing the back, and also shifting the tire position, but after reading your suggestions I realized I could let all the air out of the tire.  When I did that it wasn't too hard to move it and the valve came right out, and I was able to easily inflate it.  Really appreciate your help!